# background-size: cover on smaller DIVs

Tags: css, background-image, image-resizing

As we all know, `using background-size: cover` makes the background-image automatically scale perfectly on the browser's viewport.

Although, if we apply it on a DIV that has a smaller size, say for example 100x100px, the image will still scale, not based on the container DIV but on the total browser's viewport, resulting in showing only part of the image.

Is there any workaround for this, without considering `background-size: 100% 100%`, which doesn't really scale it by maintaining the proportions?

The `background-size: cover` is very useful to have a simple resize on the fly without using JS or either server side modifications.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got an example? I'm pretty sure I used cover on smaller divs without any issues before. And background size can also be: 100% auto or auto 100%

Comment: I don't know why it's not working properly on JSfiddle, have a look at this: http://pastie.org/4615936

Comment: Try not using fixed :) http://jsfiddle.net/vnMeK/ btw, do you know the actual difference between cover and contain?

Comment: seems good, give a second to test it with my environment. I'll let you know so you can post it as and answer and I can mark it as accepted

Comment: GREAT! It's working! post it as answer so I can mark it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy of comment so poster can accept:

Try not using fixed :) [jsfiddle.net/vnMeK](http://jsfiddle.net/vnMeK)

Note that not all browser support this, there is a semi working filter for IE.

Comment: Although I personally don't really care for older browsers, they should update :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure what you want is `background-size: contain`.

Comment: not working, it's almost the same as "cover", but it doesn't really fix it. Please check the pastie link on my comment above.